# How can I calculate a new column in data.table fast?

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I have two data.tables in `R` like this:

Ticks

```
        ask     bid          createTime
 1: 106.788 106.487 2018-03-01 00:00:01
 2: 106.788 106.487 2018-03-01 00:00:01
 3: 106.788 106.487 2018-03-01 00:00:02
 4: 106.788 106.487 2018-03-01 00:00:02
 5: 106.788 106.487 2018-03-01 00:00:03
         .         .
         .         .
992698: 105.730 105.431 2018-03-06 23:59:56
992699: 105.730 105.431 2018-03-06 23:59:56
992700: 105.732 105.431 2018-03-06 23:59:57
992701: 105.732 105.431 2018-03-06 23:59:57
992702: 105.732 105.431 2018-03-06 23:59:59
```

And Bars:

```
     volume                from                  to
  1.196550000 2018-03-01 00:00:00 2018-03-01 00:01:00
  2.233350000 2018-03-01 00:01:00 2018-03-01 00:02:00
  3.201950000 2018-03-01 00:02:00 2018-03-01 00:03:00
  4.97700000 2018-03-01 00:03:00 2018-03-01 00:04:00
  5.34200000 2018-03-01 00:04:00 2018-03-01 00:05:00
                .         .
                .         .     
8068:53800000 2018-03-06 23:55:00 2018-03-06 23:56:00
```

So, I want for every row in Bars table calculate Ticks count, where creatime >= from and creatime < to. Like this:

```
    volume                from                  to     TicksCount
  1.196550000 2018-03-01 00:00:00 2018-03-01 00:01:00     187
  2.233350000 2018-03-01 00:01:00 2018-03-01 00:02:00     72
  3.201950000 2018-03-01 00:02:00 2018-03-01 00:03:00     56
  4.97700000 2018-03-01 00:03:00 2018-03-01 00:04:00      58
  5.34200000 2018-03-01 00:04:00 2018-03-01 00:05:00      52
```

I've found the way how to do it, but it works slowly.
I tried to do this:

```
    Bars <- Bars[, TicksCount:= sapply(1:nrow(Bars), function(i) {
    nrow(Tick[Bars$from[i] <= createTime & createTime < Bars$to[i]])
  })]
```

Maybe who knows how to make it faster???
Help please!)

Comment: Maybe `Bars[, n := Ticks[.SD, on=.(createTime >= from, createTime <= to), .N, by=.EACHI]$N]` Not really sure since your example isn't reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.table::foverlaps() is fast and does what you're after:

Your two tables:

```
ticks <-
  data.table(
    ask = runif(1e5, 0, 1e5),
    bid = runif(1e5, 0, 1e5),
    createTime = runif(1e5, 0, 1e3)
  )

bars <-
  data.table(
    volume = runif(1e3, 0, 1e3),
    from = seq(0, 1e3 - 1, 1),
    to = seq(1, 1e3)
  )
```

To use foverlaps(), you need to have two tables with two ranges, not just one table with a range. So, add a helper column to ticks to create a temporary range:

```
ticks[, helper := createTime]
```

Then, create an ID for each bar group (assuming no duplicates, and no overlapping ranges in Bars):

```
bars[, bar.id := .I]
```

Each table has to have a data.table key where key1 is range start and key2 is range end:

```
setkey(ticks, createTime, helper)
setkey(bars, from, to)
```

Then, run a 'within' foverlaps on the datasets where x is Ticks and y is Bars. This creates a new table by joining x and y on overlapping ranges (where x ranges fall in y ranges). The second step below aggregates the new table, counting ticks by bar.id, and the third step joins that aggregated table back to Bars, adding the field ticksCount to Bars.

```
foverlaps(ticks, bars, type = 'within')[,
    .(ticksCount = .N), .(bar.id)
        ][bars, on = 'bar.id']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this easy solution using in another way `sapply`:

```
f<-function(createTime,Bars)
{
  return(sum(Bars$from <= createTime & createTime < Bars$to))
}

Bars$TickCount<-sapply(Ticks$createTime,f,Bars=Bars)
```

Your output:

```
Bars
   volume                from                  to TickCount
1 1.19655 2018-03-01 00:00:00 2018-03-01 00:01:00         2
2 2.23335 2018-03-01 00:00:00 2018-03-01 00:02:00         2
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But your code works in other way. Can you explain, please?

Comment: For every values of createTime the function count how many rows in Bars respect the condition: Bars$from <= createTime & createTime < Bars$to. The number is added in a new column called TickCount